# IP Geolocation country recognition

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, maxmind

what is the best practice to redirect a website visitor from a country like i.e. Russia RU.

I use a geolocation IP resolver. Where do I place the vb code for my asp.net website in order to handle all kinds of webrequests?

I did following steps:

1. Global.asax 
   Session_Start: If Ip from RU > then redirect to mysite.ru
2. Masterpage.master.vb
   Page_Load: If Ip from RU > then redirect to mysite.ru

Is these a best practice in your opinion?

Comment: It seems like a good start.

Comment: Is the code in masterpage.master.vb necessary? Otherwise it reduces my remaining paid queries.

Comment: Try commenting the code on the masterpage, since the Global is a level above it, and already handles the IP resolver.

Comment: I would put this in the MasterPage for sure. Much easier to redirect your users ...